# How to change default label 'Choose', in primeng p-multiselect (placeholder)

Tags: angular, primeng

I want to change the default label value which is set 'Choose' by default in primeng p-multiSelect dropdown placeholder. I want to change that word to 'Select' or 'Please Select' or any keyword needed.

I tried this in .ts file:

```
@Input() _defaultLabel: string = 'Select';
```

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcxUC.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `defaultLabel` property to change the default label.

For example:

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="cities" formControlName="selectedCities" [defaultLabel]="'Please Select'"></p-multiSelect>
```

Answer (score 1):

Official [Documentation](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/multiselect) suggests to use `placeholder` as defaultLabel property is deprecated.

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="cities" placeholder="Please Select"></p-multiSelect>
```

Comment: placeholder is not working for me in p-multiSelect. When I leave out either defaultLabel and placeholder, 'Choose' automatically shows up as placeholder text. If I want to change the text to 'Select', then I add the property defaultLabel="Select" and it works. However, if I instead use placeholder="Select", it is ignored and it still uses 'Choose' as the placeholder text. I am using primeng 9.1.3